# How to reinstall QGIS 2.18 as qgs-ltr

Tags: qgis, installation

I updated QGIS and accidentally rewrote 2.18 as ltr with 3.4 Madeira.
My apps work with older version. This means there must be qgis-full and qgis-ltr with version 2.18 to make them work correctly.
How can I restore my previous installation or find packages for installation from local folder.
I use Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Did you even google before asking? Go here: http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/, download your desired version, then install it. Also, QGIS-developers urge users to upgrade since 2,18 is not supported anymore.

Comment: The files are likely to still be there in your local packages directory, but they won't show up in the OSGeo4W installer without edits being made to the _setup.ini_ file, which is not straightforward. Answering @AndreJ 's comment about which elements are missing from the standalone install might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can download older versions of QGIS here:

http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/

2.18 is however no longer supported. So there will be no more bug fixes. 3.4 is now the ltr release.

**Edit:**

So my comment wasn't quite correct. You can still install QGIS 2.18 through the OSGeo4W installer, it won't be the LTR, since it is not the LTR. But it can be installed. You just need to untick "Hide obsolete packages":

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me. I need full Osgeo4W64 install with 2.18 as ltr.

Comment: You cannot get QGIS 2.18 through the OSGeo4W installer anymore.

Comment: What do you miss when using the 2.18 standalone version?